Migrate @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.ClassType") to Spring Boot 3
I have the following code which I want to migrate to Spring Boot 3:
  @Column(name = "OPTION_TYPE")
  @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.ClassType")
  private Class<T> clazz;

Example demo:
https://github.com/rcbandit111/jpa_class_store_migration_poc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/jpa/store/poc/EnumeratedAccountOption.java
I get error:
Cannot resolve method 'type'

Do you know how I can migrate this code?
EDIT:
I tried to use:
@Column(name = "OPTION_TYPE")
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JAVA_OBJECT)
private Class<T> clazz;

I get this error:
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to determine SQL type name for column 'option_type' of table 'account_options' because there is no type mapping for org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes code: 2000 (JAVA_OBJECT)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
        ... 92 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to determine SQL type name for column 'option_type' of table 'account_options' because there is no type mapping for org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes code: 2000 (JAVA_OBJECT)


Spring Boot 3 upgraded to Hibernate 6.
with Hibernate 6 @Type annotation can be replaced with @JdbcTypeCode to make the code work.
@Column(name = "OPTION_TYPE")
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JAVA_OBJECT)
private Class<T> clazz;

Basic Test class
@TestInstance(value=Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class EnumeratedAccountOptionTest {
 private EnumeratedAccountOption<ExampleEnum> option;

@BeforeAll
public void setUp() {
    option = new EnumeratedAccountOption<>("Test Option", ExampleEnum.VALUE_ONE);
}

@Test
public void testGetOptionValue() {
    assertEquals(ExampleEnum.VALUE_ONE, option.getOptionValue());
}

@Test
public void testGetClazz() {
    assertEquals(ExampleEnum.class, option.getClazz());
}
@Test
public void testSetClazz() {
    option.setClazz(ExampleEnum.class);
    assertEquals(ExampleEnum.class, option.getClazz());
}
private enum ExampleEnum {
    VALUE_ONE,
    VALUE_TWO
}
}


I get error: Attribute value must be a class literal

sorry with @Convert you have to define your own convert, but I think you can try @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JAVA_OBJECT) instead. Let me know if it works, I will update the answer as well
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/SqlTypes.html

I replaced the code but I can't test it. I created this test code: https://github.com/rcbandit111/jpa_class_store_migration_poc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/jpa/store/poc/EnumeratedAccountOption.java   Any idea for a valid test?

added basic test class example

Is it working properly?

you can commit here https://github.com/rcbandit111/jpa_class_store_migration_poc/ and try

Unfortunately I get error during startup. Please see into post error stack.

can you update your demo so that I can look into your issue?

I asked about this issue in Hibernate user group forum. It turns out that this is a bug and they advised me to open a bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17974
